# mapkit zoom out and then zoom in

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have a zoomed in map. When user picks a new poi I would like to zoom out (animated) and after animation zoom in to the new poi.

However, it's only zooming out, not in. If I use animated:false when zooming out it is working.

How to zoom in when the map is done zoomed out animated?

```
  func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {

    //Är kartan inzoomad.. zooma ut först.
    if isZoomed
    {
        let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
            20000, 20000)
        OverviewMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: false)

    }

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate,
        regionRadius * 4.0, regionRadius * 4.0)
    OverviewMap.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
    isZoomed=true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure one setRegion animation has completed prior to calling the next setRegion.

look into the [MKmapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html) `regionDidChangeAnimated` method. This will allow you to react to the completion of the setRegion animated and chain the next setRegion animation.

Comment: It's important to note that this delegate can be called numerous times during a change.  Therefore the fact that this delegate is called doesn't necessarily mean that the animation actually completed.

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you want. didSelectAnnotationView fires when the user taps on a pin.

```
var zoomingIn = false
var zoomingAnnotation:MKAnnotation

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView)
{
    let pin = view as! MKPinAnnotationView
    zoomInOnPin(pin.annotation!)
}

func zoomInOnPin(annotation:MKAnnotation) {
    let zoomOutRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: mapView.region.center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.09, longitudeDelta: 0.09))
    zoomingIn = true
    zoomingAnnotation = annotation
    mapView.setRegion(zoomOutRegion, animated: true)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if let annotation = zoomingAnnotation where zoomingIn == true {
        zoomingIn = false
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: zoomingAnnotation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.07, longitudeDelta: 0.07))
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```